# Mac OSX App crashed after a user logged in

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, crash, crashlytics

I am not sure what this crash means. It happened to one of my users after they logged in. This is the report I got from crashlytics. This report seems very vague.

```
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x00007fff8dae50e6 objc_release + 22
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x00007fff8dae465a (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 502
2  CoreFoundation                 0x00007fff8df459e2 _CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 50
3  CoreFoundation                 0x00007fff8df7d7cc __CFRunLoopRun + 1644
4  CoreFoundation                 0x00007fff8df7cf25 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309
5  HIToolbox                      0x00007fff92333a0d RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 226
6  HIToolbox                      0x00007fff923337b7 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 479
7  HIToolbox                      0x00007fff923335bc _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 65
8  AppKit                         0x00007fff9093726e _DPSNextEvent + 1434
9  AppKit                         0x00007fff909368bb -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 122
10 AppKit                         0x00007fff9092a9bc -[NSApplication run] + 553
11 AppKit                         0x00007fff909157a3 NSApplicationMain + 940
12 libdyld.dylib                  0x00007fff8ba235fd start + 1
```

Comment: There is nothing there. Add register values. Some of them might include address.

Answer (score 0):

The crash log indicates that you have a problem with your memory management; you have over-released an object, and that is showing up as a crash when the autorelease pool fires.  If you are not familiar with these concepts, then you need to [read about autorelease pools in Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html).  If you understand these ideas and need help finding the crash, then I would recommend (1) finding a reproducible case for the crasher, (2) turning on `NSZombie` (Google is your friend), which is easy to do with the checkbox in Xcode's Edit Scheme panel, and (3) breaking on the appropriate `NSZombie` method to find out what type of object is being over-released, which should give you a bit more information, at least.  Running Xcode's static analyzer on your code might also help to find the bug without needing to do any of those steps (i.e., without needing a reproducible case).